# How can i Import all (and only) Tables of a specific User from a Oracle DB with Sqoop into Hive

Tags: oracle, hive, sqoop

I have a Database with lots of Tables (over 600) and want to import all of them into Hive using sqoop. Thats the command i have used:

```
./sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//185.2.252.52:1521/orcl --username TEST --password test
```

The Import allways fails because sqoop tries to import some oracle system Tables that dont belong to the user.

```
    ./sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//185.2.252.52:1521/orcl --username TEST --password test
```

list-tables lists the same tables that following sql query does:

```
select * from all_tables;
```

Instead i'd like to list and import(my guess ist that it are the same tables) the same tables that this query would:

```
select * from user_tables;
```

Is there a way to restrict the importing Tables via sqoop? And if not, is there a way to configure the user rights in a way, so that "select * from all_tables" will give me the same tables than "select * from user_tables" ??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a synonym called `ALL_TABLES` in your schema that points to the `USER_TABLES` view.

```
SQL> select count(*) from all_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
      2769

SQL> select count(*) from user_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        24

SQL> create synonym all_tables for user_tables;

Synonym created.

SQL> select count(*) from all_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        24

SQL>
```

That should fool the script, unless it explicitly qualifies the `ALL_TABLES` view with its owner (eg: `SYS.ALL_TABLES`).